# Method File.renameTo

Tags: java, file

I am trying to rename a file, now the problem is I can rename the file in JUnit alone, but when I put the operation in a for loop, it didn't work.

```
public String createFile(){
    //generate a file
    //return a invariable filepath
}
for(int i=0;i<someconditions;i++){
    File f1 = new File(createFile());
    File f2 = new File(//random filename);
    f1.renameTo(f2); //always return false
}
```

But it works if I just rename one file like:

```
File f1 = new File(path);
File f2 = new File(newPath);
f1.renameTo(f2);
```

now i find the wrong place,it didn't work in this code,but i don't know why:

```
    public void renametest(){
    String path = "E:\\wk7\\Export\\__temp__dir\\temp_name.xml";
    String type = "123";
    tttt(path, type);
}

public String tttt(String path,String type){
    String head = "MASS";
    String absSec = ExUtils.getAbsSec();
    File file = new File(path);
    Long crc = ExUtils.geCrc32(file);
    String name = head+"_"+absSec+"_"+type+"_"+crc+".xml";
    String newPath = path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("\\"))+"\\"+name;
    File newFile = new File(newPath);
    Boolean b = file.renameTo(newFile);
    if(b){
        //do something
        return newPath;
    }else{
        //do something
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: are there any runtime errors?

Comment: Your `for()` loop never terminates - so you are renaming the same file over and over and over again.

Comment: if your code actually is like the for loop that you have shown here, then it will only rename the first time and then always fail as second time onwards the original file doesnt exist anymore

Comment: Do you call `createFile` within the `for` loop? Please note that `renameTo` is a kind of cut/paste...

Comment: sorry,the for loop is not the problem.in each loop it will create a new file. no runtime errors,just return false.

Comment: 1. Does createFile() really create a file in the file system, or only a File? 2. Is the 'random filename' really random enough? 3. Are the source and target files always on the same file system?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted. try creating a SSCCE and we'll check it.

Comment: @EJP 1.createFile() is really create a file in system,a xml file. 2,the random filename is milliseconds+crc32+some other verify code. 3.the target is in the same directory with the source file

Comment: now i find the wrong place,but i don't know why.

Comment: i know why ,that's my fault,i didn't close the inputstream in method "getcrc32".thanks for everyones help/